# Solr, Django, and PDF Search

Tags: java, python, django, pdf, solr

Can someone provide at least a manageable example for using Solr to search/index PDF's, and how I might integrate that with Django? I've downloaded the latest version, and have spent the last couple days trying to figure it out, but to no avail.

Most of the answers here are links to documentation. Here is Haystacks note on the subject:

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/rich_content_extraction.html

Videos and tutorials are equally arcane and technical - seriously, here is "beginner" tutorial that's 2 hours long (just for part 1!) and that goes into tokenizers, analyzers, inverted index technique, etc:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WIbU3ZlTe4

I'm using Windows, Django 1.8, and Python 2.7.

Comment: There is nothing like a simple example for the requirements you describe. 
Start with a minimal example with woosh as a backend, just indexing one model property. If you can successful query this solution from a frontend search mask make the next step which might be adding PDF indexing functionality or swapping woosh against solr.